# Jquery unable to send request to servlet error 404 not found

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am sending a ajax request to a servlet .
Ajax Code:

```
                 $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "/SignUp",
                        data: dataString,
                        // if received a response from the server
                        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log("Transfering ");

                        },

                        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                        }
                    });
              }
```

Servlet Path:
My servlet is live on hosting now.It is under:
 **domain/public_html/WEB-INF/CLASSES/controller/auth/SignUp**

My Web.xml Entry

```
             <servlet>
               <description></description>
               <display-name>SignUp</display-name>
               <servlet-name>SignUp</servlet-name>
               <servlet-class>.controller.auth.SignUp</servlet-class>
            </servlet>

             <servlet-mapping>
                 <servlet-name>SignUp</servlet-name>
                  <url-pattern>/SignUp</url-pattern>
             </servlet-mapping>
```

**[image: On Every Ajax call i am getting error 404 not found.]**

My Web.XML file is

```
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
       <display-name>CarPool</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
         <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
     <description></description>
    <display-name>Login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>controller.auth.Login</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SignUp</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SignUp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controller.auth.SignUp</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SignUp</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/SignUp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
   <display-name>ResetPassword</display-name>
   <servlet-name>ResetPassword</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>controller.auth.ResetPassword</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ResetPassword</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ResetPassword</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
```

Comment: can you post the name of packge of servlet?

Comment: @Abdelhak  servlet is in  controller.auth package

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `servlet-class` path from this:

```
    <servlet-class>.controller.auth.SignUp</servlet-class>
```

To with removing the first dot `.`:

```
    <servlet-class>controller.auth.SignUp</servlet-class>
```

Here write the right path using `contextPath` like this:

```
 <script>var contextPath = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}";</script>
   url :contextPath + "/SignUp",
```

Comment: tried removing . as well but still same error.
Do i need to set context path

Comment: @Abdelak
same response even with contextPath .
and when i console.log(contextPath);
no value displayed or it output blank...

Comment: Try to post your full  the web.xml @mohitsharma

Comment: @Abdelak posted my full web.xml